# TypeError modifying Odoo 8 native module

Tags: python, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am trying to modify Odoo's functionality through custom module. The thing is to change Project task copying functionality. Natively, when creating a new project from a template with tasks having work summaries, work summaries are not copied (I would like to keep them). I found the function that copies tasks but I am getting stuck with this...

This is the error I get (which I don't understand because it refers to **duplicate_template()** when I am not modifying that method from project class):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 540, in
_handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 577, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 313, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 310, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 806, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 406, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in
_call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 399, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs) 
TypeError: duplicate_template() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)
```

And here is my code:

**mymodule.py**

```
import openerp
from openerp import models,fields,api
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class task(osv.osv):
    _inherit="project.task"

    @api.multi
    def copy_data(self, default=None, context=None):
        if default is None:
            default = {}
        current = self.browse(cr, uid, id, context=context)
        if not default.get('name'):
            default['name'] = _("%s (copy)") % current.name
        if 'remaining_hours' not in default:
            default['remaining_hours'] = current.planned_hours

        default['work_ids'] = current.work_ids
        return super(task, self).copy_data(cr, uid, id, default, context)
```

> **default['work_ids'] = current.work_ids** was added by me - it was not included in original function.

Any ideas about why I am getting that wrong?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all read official documentation before working on Odoo. Why? Because odoo 8 introduced new api which you must use, not the old one. That's official recommendations.

So again error occurs because you haven't read official documentation. What `@api.multi` decorator does? It passes arguments to the function cr, uid, ids and context. So because of that `self` is current RecordSet without iteration. So in order to use `@api.multi` correctly you must iterate between records. So you must use

```
@api.multi
def something(self):
    for rec in self:
        # Do the job here for single record
```

And again because you don't know odoo-8 and still developing modules in new api `browse` takes only id.

I told you everything you need to know. I'm not going to write function for you for free and PLEASE first read official documentation and then ask on stackoverflow.

Regards

Comment: Even though your answer was completely arrogant, it was very helpful. I will, again, read the documentation. Just to make things clear: I did not expect anyone to write code for free for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are having an old API compatibility issue:

The right way to inherit the `copy_data` method is this:

```
@api.multi
def copy_data(self, default=None):
    #  your stuff here
    return super(ClassName, self).copy_data(default)
```

Also you are mixing old API with an already decorated method with the new API, so your method should look like this:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class Task(models.Model):
    _inherit="project.task"

    @api.multi
    def copy_data(self, default=None):

        if default is None:
            default = {}
        for current in self;
            current = self
            if not default.get('name'):
                default['name'] = _("%s (copy)") % current.name
            if 'remaining_hours' not in default:
                default['remaining_hours'] = current.planned_hours

            default['work_ids'] = current.work_ids
        return super(Task, self).copy_data(default)
```

Since you are decorating with `@api.multi` you may be receiving more than one record in `self`, so you need to iterate in `self`.

The signature of the class needs to be `model.Models`

Best regards

Comment: Thank you very much, Oscar! I am getting UnboundLocalError: local variable 'default' referenced before assignment. Is that because I need to replace something? Regards.

Comment: There is no way that the error is being triggered by this method, because `default` is in all the namespace of the method, I think the error is in some other method.

Comment: Thank you so much!